# FastDDS server only for certain topics

Tags: data-distribution-service

For context see [this robotics stackexchange question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107923/preventing-interference-and-minimizing-network-traffic). Given the DDS xml configuration file underneath, can I somehow specify that the DDS server with port 11888 should only receive ROS topics `/namespace/topic1` and `/namespace/topic2`?

Thanks in advance!

([Reposted from this robotics stackexchange question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/109629/fastdds-server-only-for-certain-topics), because I assume there are also DDS experts outside robotics)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dds>
    <profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
        <participant profile_name="my_profile" is_default_profile="true">
            <rtps>
                <builtin>
                    <discovery_config>
                        <discoveryProtocol>SIMPLE</discoveryProtocol>
                        <discoveryServersList>
                        
                            <RemoteServer prefix="44.53.00.5f.45.50.52.4f.53.49.4d.41">
                                <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                                    <locator>
                                        <udpv4>
                                            <address>127.0.0.1</address>
                                            <port>11811</port>
                                        </udpv4>
                                    </locator>
                                </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                            </RemoteServer>
                            
                            <RemoteServer prefix="44.53.01.5f.45.50.52.4f.53.49.4d.41">
                                <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                                    <locator>
                                        <udpv4>
                                            <address>127.0.0.1</address>
                                            <port>11888</port>
                                        </udpv4>
                                    </locator>
                                </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                            </RemoteServer>

                        </discoveryServersList>
                    </discovery_config>
                </builtin>
            </rtps>
        </participant>
    </profiles>
</dds>
```